# How to make round visibility of array of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inside 3 divs inside one one aside another and every of those 3 divs shows one image.
How to make that at the time only one is visible and after 5 seconds visible fade out and next fade in  and same in round indefinite time.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest javascript. What have you tried?

Comment: use setinterval and toggle

Comment: Please post your attempts

Comment: what issue you are having?

Comment: Search for 'carousel' or 'slider'. There are hundreds of plugins that do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do Some thing like This

```
 var i = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $("#container").find("div").each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $("#container").find("div:eq(" + i + ")").slideDown(500);
        i++;
        if (i==2) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, 5000);
```